# Blender 2.93 LTS pose roll deprecated?

Tags: transforms

When looking https://youtu.be/QDWzqcc9U00?t=28

But in 2.93 LTS, I can not see this roll value.
How can I adjust the roll in pose mode, in 2.93 LTS (Bones>roll)?
(rotate yy fails for me)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to be in *Edit* mode to have access to the *Bone > Transform > Roll* value (or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> and type the value). To roll a bone on its Z axis in *Pose* mode, press <kbd>R</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd>.

Comment: OK roll appears only in edit mode. Thank you !